# How to create a package that only contains launch files

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, roslaunch, package.xml, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to create a package that only holds launch files for packages that I installed using `apt-get`.
Let's say my package, called `ros-package` has the following folder structure:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── launch
│   ├── a.launch
│   ├── all.launch
│   ├── b.launch
│   └── c.launch
└── package.xml
```

I want `a.launch`, `b.launch`, and `c.launch` each look something like this:

```
<launch>
    <node name="listener_node" pkg="hello_world" type="listener" output="screen"/>
</launch>
```

and `all.launch` just includes the other three and launches all of them.
So I want to be able to "build" this package with `catkin` or `colcon`, `source install/setup.bash`, and run all with the following command:

```
roslaunch ros-package all.launch
```

Now I'm not sure how to setup the `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml` files to achieve this. Any help would be much appreciated.

With anything I've attempted the launch files don't get included in the install directory and are not found as a result.

Bonus question: I also have a config.yml file that I want to be copied into the install directory as well as it is passed on as an argument to one of the launch files.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367735/how-to-create-a-package-that-only-contains-launch-files/) by [SuchConfuse](https://answers.ros.org/users/65615/suchconfuse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The major thing is to install them (from [here](https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox/blob/44c9f840b01b1c9b5ed351c7d0074c641ee3e21c/slam_toolbox/CMakeLists.txt#L184-L186)):

```
install(DIRECTORY launch/ 
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)
```

and still call the catkin macro with your relevant info (might be just empty for you) https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox/blob/44c9f840b01b1c9b5ed351c7d0074c641ee3e21c/slam_toolbox/CMakeLists.txt#L57.

You shouldn't have to do anything new to the package.xml if it is otherwise correctly setup.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SuchConfuse](https://answers.ros.org/users/65615/suchconfuse/) on 2020-12-16**:
Thanks, this is better than adding the files each individually.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So it turns out I was having problems due to a typo in my launch file name. To answer the question, my `package.xml` only includes the default tags. My `CMakeLists.txt` has an additional entry for copying the launch files over to the install directory:

```
install(FILES
    launch/a.launch
    launch/b.launch
    launch/c.launch
    launch/all.launch
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/launch
)
```

The additional `config.yml` file can also be copied over to the install directory in the same manner.

---

Originally posted by [SuchConfuse](https://answers.ros.org/users/65615/suchconfuse/) with karma: 13 on 2020-12-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1